# Unpredictable behaviour in simple loop to check if line & col exists in file

Tags: c, loops, file-io, compiler-optimization, fgetc

Below is the code for a *function* that checks if the line and column 'co-ordinates' given to it are valid for a file whose pointer is passed to it.

12 hours of confusion later, I have no idea why this behaves so *randomly*.

On running this on it own source file, it throws errors at any column value greater than `10`. I assumed that some overenthusiastic compiler optimisations are juxtaposing the `q` count variable and the `chk` variable, and since `'\n'` has decimal val `10`, breaking my loop.

To assumption, I tried compiling with GCC (previously I was using Apple Clang). Same problem.

On each file, it fails at any value greater than some *random* col value. On one file, this was `12`, on another, `15`.. **Why ??**

```
void check_valid(FILE *ffind,long long line,long long col){

    long long unsigned i,q; int f=0; i=0;int chk;q=0; // counter, character holder and control variables
    if(line>=1 && col>=1){ // -ve lines/columns invalid
        while(i<line){
            // tests if line is valid for file
            chk = fgetc(ffind);
            if(chk==EOF){
                f=-1;printf("\nInvalid Line.\n");break; // line invalid if EOF encountered before reaching line count
            }
            else if(chk=='\n')
                i++;    
        }
        if(f==0){
            //if line was valid, checks if the col value is valid.
            rewind(ffind); 
            while(i<line-1){chk=fgetc(ffind);if(chk=='\n')i++;} // brings fptr @ last char of prev. line, so the next char read is 1st char of given line.
            while(q<col){
                chk=fgetc(ffind);
                if(chk==EOF||chk=='\n'){ // if EOF or newline found before reaching col, col is invalid.
                    f=-1;printf("\nInvalid column = %d\n",chk);break;
                }
                else
                    q++;
            }
            if(f==0) printf("\nValid !\n");
        }
}
```

Comment: [How to Debug a Small Program](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) would help. Unless you found behaviors are different between compile flags.

Comment: `if(f==0)` At this point `i == line` and you never reset it.

Comment: @user13863346 Now that the major problem is fixed would be a good time to test it some more ;-) Try for example a file where the last line is not terminated with a `\n`.

Comment: @LouisGo extremely helpful, will remember. I had already done: turn on all compiler warnings, obtain a rubber duck, break your code up into smaller methods, each of which does exactly one logical operation, write a technical specification for each method, double check that your specifications contain all the preconditions and postconditions of every method, write assertions that verify your preconditions and postconditions, write test cases for each method that verify that it is behaving correctly, write down on a piece of paper the exact action you expect the program to take on every line.

Comment: @dxiv I think we found yet another bug :(

Comment: @user13863346 My suggestion would be to get rid of the second `while` altogether. Just count the characters while you read them in the first loop when `i == line - 1`, and if you reach the `col`'th character then the position is valid (and you could post that as a better self-answer).

Comment: @dxiv the reason I used  2  `while()`loops was because to check the validity of the col, would require stopping at the end of the previous line and reading from the first character of the given line , which ofc requires that it is known that the given line exists.

Comment: @user13863346 You could just do `q++` after each `fgetc` and `q = 0` after `chk=='\n'`. And when `i == line - 1` and `q == col` you will have found the position.

Comment: @dxiv I'm not trying to find the position but rather find if the position was valid, i.e, make sure it didn't occur after an EOF

Comment: @user13863346 It's the same thing. (Too long for a comment, posted as an answer.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The posted code has two problems.

- `if(f==0){ /* line was valid */ }` does not reset `i = 0` before the following `while(i<line-1)` loop. Because `i == line-1` after the previous loop, the second `while` gets skipped altogether, and reading proceeds from the beginning of the file, instead of line `line`.
- A line is not counted as complete until `if(chk=='\n')` evaluates to true. This skips over the last line in the file if it is not terminated with a `\n` newline. In the simplest case, a file with just one (non-empty) line but without a `\n` terminator will always fail the `check_valid` test.

While each of those can be easily fixed, a more direct way is to do the checks in a single pass.

```
while(i < line){
    chk = fgetc(ffind);
    if(chk == EOF){
        printf("\nInvalid %s.\n", (i == line - 1) ? "Column" : "Line"); break;
    }
    else if(chk == '\n'){
        if(i == line - 1){
            printf("\nInvalid Column.\n"); break;
        }
        i++; q = 0;
    }
    else if(i == line - 1 && q == col - 1){
        printf("\nValid Line/Column.\n"); break;
    }
    else
        q++;
}
```

Comment: where does your code leave the file pointer in case of valid index ?

Comment: @user13863346 At the character that follows the one at `line, col` (or `EOF` if that's the very last one in the file).

Comment: @user13863346 Parsing code (yours or others') and using the debugger are both prime skills in this game. Acquiring them is part of the road to C, though it may not always be fun ;-)

Comment: could you initialise the variables in this answer so that I can know if it's 1-based or 0-based ?

Comment: @user13863346 This is based on the code you posted, so the indexes here are 0-based.

Comment: dxiv, Couldn't this just be a `while(1)` since we test for the `break` condition within the loop *anyways* ?

Comment: @user13863346 It could, as long as it was verified that `line > 0` before the loop.

Comment: Brilliant. Does it make a difference in that computation is reduced , or no ?

Comment: @user13863346 I wouldn't expect any practical difference. I/O calls like `fgetc` are many times more expensive than one integer compare, even if redundant.