# Attempting File I/O with lines and columns, problems with positioning the FILE *

Tags: arrays, c, file-io

I am attempting to write 2 functions :

- One which moves a FILE* to the passed index
- Other which copies contents from a FILE* from between 2 indexes to a string.

Very inexplicable errors are occurring, and I have been trying to fix it for quite a few hours now, and am about to collapse, please point out my folly.

Behaviour Observed :

1. `chknbuff()` is skipping the last char, so I taped on some code that would fix that.
2. Reading beyond the 1st line (ln=2, col=x for eg.) triggers the EOF error in `chkncpy()` in other files .
3. Suppressing `chknmove()`'s EOF warning gives `Segmentation Fault`s , which means an `EOF` is really being encountered.

Code :

```c
#include <stdio.h>
/*-------Function-Definitions------------*/
int chknmove(FILE *tomove,long long line,long long col){
// moves FILE * to line & col passed
    rewind(tomove); int chk,f; long long i,q; i=0; q=0; f=0;
    if(line>=1 && col>=1){
        while(i < line){
            chk = fgetc(tomove);
            if(chk == EOF){
                printf("\n Invalid Index.\n");f=-1;break;
            }
            else if(chk == '\n'){
                if(i == line - 1){
                    printf("\n Invalid Index.\n");f=-1;break;
                }
                i++; q = 0;
            }
            else if(i == line - 1 && q == col - 1){
                break;
            }
            else
                q++;
        }
        if(f==0)
            fseek(tomove,-1,SEEK_CUR);
    }
    else{
        printf("\n Invalid Index.\n");f=-1;
    }
    return f;
}
int chknbuff(FILE *source, char *dest, long long beginln, long long begincol, long long endln, long long endcol){
// copies file contents from beginning line&cols to end lines&cols to a string.
    int z = chknmove(source,beginln,begincol);
    if(z==0){
        int chk; long long i,q,m; i=0; q=0; m=0; //endcol++;
        if(endln>=1 && endcol>=1 && endln>=beginln){
            while(i < endln){
                chk = fgetc(source);
                if(chk == EOF){
                    printf("\n Invalid Index1.\n");z=-1;break;
                }
                else if(chk == '\n'){
                    if(i == endln-1){
                        printf("\n Invalid Index2.\n");z=-1;break;
                    }
                    dest[m]=chk;m++; i++; q = 0;
                }
                else if(i == endln-1 && q == endcol-1 ){
                    break;
                }
                else{
                    dest[m]=chk;m++; q++;
                }
            }
            if(z==0){
                fseek(source,-1,SEEK_CUR);
                chk = fgetc(source);
                if(chk!=EOF)
                    dest[m]=chk; m++;
            }
            dest[m++]='\0';
        }
        else{
            printf("\n Invalid Index3.\n");z=-1;
        }
    }
    return z;
}
/*---------------------------------------------*/

int main(){
    FILE * write = fopen("xyz","w");
    if(write == NULL)
        perror("\n Error ");
    else{
        printf("\n Filename : "); char fpart[501]; scarf("%500[^\n]",fpart); FILE * part = fopen(fpart,"r");
        if(part==NULL)
            perror("\n Error ");
        else{
            long long beginln, begincol, endln, endcol; char sep1,sep2;
            printf("\n Starting Index : ");     scanf("%lld%c%lld",&beginln,&sep1,&begincol); eat();
            printf("\n Terminating Index : "); scanf("%lld%c%lld",&endln,&sep2,&endcol); eat();
            char buff[MAX_F_BUFF];int f = chknbuff(part,buff,beginln,begincol,endln,endcol);
            if(f==0)
                fputs(buff,write);  
        }
        int d = fclose(write);
        if(d==EOF)
            perror("\n Failed ");
        else
            printf("\n Success.\n"); 
    }
    return 0;
}
```

*In case of any extra info needed, please comment and I will try to add it*

Comment: `[chknbuff] i=0; q=0;` The line/column indexes here should not start at `0` because the previous `chknmove` call left the file pointer set to `beginln, begincol`.

Comment: @dxiv assigning `i=beginln` & `q=begincol` results in blank strings or strings with just one char ...

Comment: @user13863346 I think you are confusing yourself because `i, q` are 0-based while `line, col` are 1-based. Besides, you now have a lot of duplication between the code in the two functions. You could do it all with one function if you modified the first one to check for both begin/end conditions, start writing to the string when the begin condition is hit, and stop writing when the end condition is hit.

Comment: @dxiv that is accurate, I am *very* confused... I have no clue what is happening and why. Do you recommend trying to grasp this with a debugger or with paper-pen ?

Comment: @user3629249 I have modified code to such that an M.R.E now exists in the question. Further, correcting `unsigned long long` to `long long` (which was all that showed up upon enabling **all** warnings as directed by you ) has not solved the larger issue although I am thankful for it .

Comment: @user13863346 Both ;-) Run it under the debugger, but be prepared to jot down values if needed.

Comment: @dxiv Here I go, learning the debugger properly after a long time !

Comment: If you will always be reading sequential segments (no overlap and none that start before the last ended), then get rid of `rewind(tomove);` and just let `fgetc()` advance the file position. That will eliminate all need to reposition within the file. You may also want to think about your `chknbuff()` function just taking the TO number of lines and ending column (but you will have to check before calling if `beginln == endln` and pass `endcol - begincol + 1` as the parameter in that case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following expands on my comment "*you could do it all with one function*", and does it with a single pass through the file. The characters in range are printed with `putchar(chk);`, which could be replaced with `fputc(chk, write);` or `dest[count] = chk;` to save to a file or a string buffer, instead.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// return number of characters in 'copy' range between (beginline, begincol) and (endline, endcol)
// line/col are 1-based and the 'copy' range is inclusive of both begin/end positions
long long copy_range(FILE* fyl, long long beginln, long long begincol, long long endln, long long endcol) {
    long long line, col, count; int chk;

    if (beginln < 1 || begincol < 1 || endln < beginln || (endln == beginln && endcol < begincol))
        return -1;

    // assume current file position is at the beginning, maybe 'rewind' if that's not guaranteed
    line = 1; col = 1; count = -1;

    // read the file sequentially
    // start saving characters once (beginline, begincol) is reached
    // break out of the loop after (endline, endcol) is reached
    do {
        // attempt to read character at position (line, col)
        chk = fgetc(fyl);

        // attempt failed, return error
        // check count to see whether it happened before or within the 'copy' range
        // check line to see if the entire line is past EOF vs. just the target column
        if (chk == EOF) {
            printf("\nInvalid %s %s.\n",
                (count < 0) ? "Beginning" : "Ending",
                (line == beginln) ? "Column" : "Line");
            break;
        }

        // found newline character
        if (chk == '\n') {
            // error if looking for (beginln, begincol) and newline found on beginln before begincol
            //    or if looking for (endln, endcol) and newline found on endln before endcol
            if (line == ((count < 0) ? beginln : endln)) {
                printf("\nInvalid %s Column.\n",
                    (count < 0) ? "Beginning" : "Ending");
                break;
            }

            // comment the following if *not* preserving newlines in 'copy' range
            if (count >= 0) {
                putchar(chk); count++;
            }

            // update position and move on
            line++; col = 1; continue;
        }

        if (line == beginln && col == begincol) {
            // enter the 'copy' range, start counting
            printf("--- begin ---\n"); count = 0;
        }
        if (count >= 0) {
            // save character if within the 'copy' range
            putchar(chk); count++;
        }
        if (line == endln && col == endcol) {
            // leave the 'copy' range, return the count
            // if saving to a string, add the nul-terminator here, but do not increment counter
            printf("\n---- end ----\n"); break;
        }
        col++;
    } while (line <= endln);

    return count;
}

int main() {
    char fpart[501];
    printf("\nEnter Filename:\n");
    if (scanf("%500[^\n]", fpart) != 1) return -1;;

    FILE* part = fopen(fpart, "r");
    if (part == NULL) return errno;

    long long beginln, begincol, endln, endcol;
    printf("\nEnter Starting Index:\n");
    if (scanf("%lld %lld", &beginln, &begincol) != 2) return -2;;
    printf("\nEnter Terminating Index:\n");
    if (scanf("%lld %lld", &endln, &endcol) != 2) return -3;

    return copy_range(part, beginln, begincol, endln, endcol) > 0;
}
```

---

[ *EDIT* ]   Following the comments, clarified to mean counting newlines as the last position on the line before, this is a modification of the above which moves the `'\n'` check after the character is processed,  and removes the now redundant newline echo.

```
long long copy_range(FILE* fyl, long long beginln, long long begincol, long long endln, long long endcol) {
    long long line, col, count; int chk;

    if (beginln < 1 || begincol < 1 || endln < beginln || endcol < ((endln == beginln) ? begincol : 1))
        return -1;

    line = 1; col = 1; count = -1;

    do {
        chk = fgetc(fyl);

        if (chk == EOF) {
            printf("\nInvalid %s %s.\n",
                (count < 0) ? "Beginning" : "Ending",
                (line == beginln) ? "Column" : "Line");
            break;
        }

        if (line == beginln && col == begincol) {
            printf("--- begin ---\n"); count = 0;
        }
        if (count >= 0) {
            putchar(chk); count++;
        }
        if (line == endln && col == endcol) {
            printf("\n---- end ----\n"); break;
        }

        if (chk == '\n') {
            if (line == ((count < 0) ? beginln : endln)) {
                printf("\nInvalid %s Column.\n",
                    (count < 0) ? "Beginning" : "Ending");
                break;
            }
            line++; col = 1;
        }
        else
            col++;
    } while (line <= endln);

    return count;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for catching the `if(endln==beginln && endcol < begincol)`. I missed that. Sharp thinking.

Comment: 1) Are those double semicolons `;;` not typos ? 2) What if the file is empty ?

Comment: 3) Shouldn't the first `if` also check for `( encol < 1 )` ? or have you implicitly done that elsewhere ?

Comment: 1) Right, those are typos, albeit harmless. 2) If the file is empty you'll hit EOF before reaching the start position. 3) That should be caught in the loop, anyway, but `endcol < 1` could be checked upfront, or even `endcol < ((endln == beginln) ? begincol : 1)` if you want to merge both checks.

Comment: 4) The user can't go to the actual `'\n'` itself - because of how this resets line/cols... Being able to address the `'\n'` itself is *important* when attempting *inserting* 'into' a file - the user must be able to add to the *end* of a line and extend it as well as write to any `line > 1 && col == 1` both of which return errors due to the reset method ... Any ideas on how this can be handled with small changes to this otherwise dandy function ?

Comment: @user13863346 The question here was about copying a range in a file between the given positions, and that's what this answer addresses. You could modify it to work for *insertions* like in your other question, but you'll need to first decide on what syntax you want to use, specifically whether and how to indicate newlines, the beginning of the file (before the first character) and EOF (after the last character).

Comment: dxiv, I don't debate your the answer's completeness - it's appropriate for the question and solves it ; I was enquiring if you have any suggestions on how it can be used to achieve resetting **after** the `'\n'` ... As for 'what syntax you want to use' - The beginning of the file and EOF is the same as here , the counting of line, however, seems like it would make sense of done @ *first* char of *next* line (if that does not exist /is followed by EOF, like how POSIX requires `\n` at end of file, then we still `line++;`) - I am not sure how this can be implemented, and suggestions would be nice

Comment: @user13863346 I was just pointing out that discussing insertions does not really belong here. It is quite a different story than copying, for example you can insert something "at EOF" i.e. past the last character in the file, but you cannot copy a range that starts at EOF. If you want to modify (or write anew) the function for insertion, first step is to define how you want it to work. Forget about implementation, just what functionality you want it to provide. Specification goes first, then code follows later.

Comment: Your right, I've continued this conversation in chat https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221188/inserting-adding-arbitrarily-into-a-file

Comment: @user13863346 Edited with a counting-newlines variant.

Answer (score 1):

In this *self-answer*, I post my approach that solved this for me. My functions in the question were a bit botched and messy, and here they no longer are.

I've solved it borrowing from [dxiv](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5538420/dxiv)'s answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63627701/13863346) , and my own meddling on how to handle `'\n'` chars . It works quite well *afaik*.

Hope it is of help to others in the future.

The functions I needed :

```c
int chknmove(FILE *tomove, long long line, long long col){
    /* Moves FILE* to given ((line,col) -1 char) , such that next char read from FILE* will be @ (line,col)
     Checks validity of index as it moves : if col not in line || EOF encountered, returns -1. */

    rewind(tomove); // rewind file 'just in case'

    int f = 0 ; // control variable which stores state (succeeded/failed) of chknmove()

    if (line < 1 || col < 1) 
    {
        f=-1; 
        printf("\n Illegal Index.\n");
        // Follows 1-based line/col index : -ve values are illegal
        return -1;
    }
    else {
        long long i,q; i = q = 0; // i = lines encountered ; q = chars encountered in line i ; both are 0-based

        while(i < line){
            int chk = fgetc(tomove); // 
            if(chk == EOF){
                printf("\nInvalid %s - beyond EOF.\n", (i == line -1 ) ? "Column" : "Line"); 
                f = -1; break;
            }
            else if(chk == '\n'){
                if(i==line-1 && q == col-1) 
                /*  1. This allows for user to directly point to the '\n' char , allowing him to append to line 
                    2.(line/col - 1) : since i & q are 0-based   */
                    break;
                else{
                    if(i == line-1 ){
                        // except if target index was the '\n' , reading beyond newline @ target line is invalid, since '\n' terminates line
                        printf("\nInvalid column for line %lld.\n",line); 
                        f=-1; break;
                    }
                    i++; q=0; // if not @ target line , reset and continue 
                }
            }
            else if(i == line-1  && q == col-1 ) // if dest index reached, break .
                break;
            else // if non-EOF , non-\n char encountered, increment q and continue.
                q++;
        }

        if(f==0){
            fseek(tomove,-1,SEEK_CUR); // So that the after returning/exiting chknmove() , the char read from FILE* is @ line,col
            return 0;
        }
        else
            return -1;
    }
}
```

**AND**

```c
int chknbuff(FILE* source, char *dest, long long beginln, long long begincol, long long endln, long long endcol) {
    /* Copies everything from FILE *source to char *dest within begining index and terminating index , if they're valid
        Returns -1 if they're invalid.*/

    if (beginln < 1 || begincol < 1 || endln < beginln || endcol < ((endln == beginln) ? begincol : 1))
        // -ve indexes and reading/writing backwards is illegal
        return -1;

    long long i, q; // i -> lines && q -> chars 
    int f=0; long long m = 0;
    if(chknmove(source,beginln,begincol)==0){ 
        // checked if begining index is valid and if so, moved to it.

        i=beginln; q=begincol; // i & q have same base as line & col , so 1-based

        while(1){
            int ch = fgetc(source);
            if(ch==EOF){
                printf("\nInvalid Terminating Index.\n");
                f=-1; break;
            }
            else if(ch=='\n'){
                if(i==endln && q==endcol){
                    dest[m]=ch; m++;
                    break;
                }
                else{
                    if(i==endln){
                        printf("Invalid column for line %lld.\n",endln);
                        f=-1; break;
                    }
                    i++; q=1; // q set to 1 -> q is 1-based !
                    dest[m]=ch; m++;
                }
            }
            else if(i==endln && q==endcol){
                dest[m]=ch; m++; break;
            }

            else{
                q++; dest[m]=ch; m++;
            }
        }
    }
    else
        f=-1;

    dest[m]='\0'; // null terminate the buffer 
    if(f==0)    return 0;
    else    return -1;
}
```

*In case of any missed errors/details please comment, I will answer ASAP*

Comment: @dxiv I've managed to fix it all and it works smoothly now ( *afaik*) , so 1) It'd be awesome if you could take a look 2) Perhaps delete your old comment since it no longer applies

Comment: Guess the last `fputc(ch,dest);` was meant to be `dest[m]=ch; m++;` (btw the more idiomatic C way to write it would be `*dest++ = ch;`;). With that, the code looks to be working now. For a stylistic observation, the main "*copy char*" action of `chknbuff` is done in 4 different places in the function, even though the logic is the same in all 4 places - copy the character if in range.

Comment: @dxiv ' *the more idiomatic C way to write it would be ...* ' Are these informal conventions written somewhere , because I'd be interested to know more, since C is a language I deeply enjoy using.And yes, I fixed the `fputc()` : ) . As for ' *copy char...is done in 4 different places* ' - yes, that's true, though it seems ' *ok* ' to me because I'd make  sense much faster  were I to read it a couple years later (subjective ?)

Comment: Don't know there is a formal list  of C idioms, but one of the first things you learnt in K&R's C book was that `strcpy` can be written as `while (*s++ = *t++);`. As for what's easier to read/parse, that is subjective to some extent. For me at least, I find it easier to follow a nested `if-if-else-else-if-else` where the common action is "factored out" and written once, rather than repeated inside each block.