# Attempting to 'insert' or 'add' into a text file - one small problem

Tags: c, file, file-io, file-pointer

Code M.R.E provided.

The symptoms are ' *simple* ' :

1. Trying on `hello\nhello\nhelloEOF` & inserting '`_`' @ `ln=2` & `col=1` (or rather any `line>1 && col==1`) the program curiously *does it right*, but eats up the `'\n'` , causing line 2 to *fuse* with line 1 - `hello_hello\nhelloEOF` , rather than `hello\n_hello\nhelloEOF`.
2. Trying on the a char in the last line of file `hello\nhello\nhelloEOF` & inserting '`_`' @ `ln=3` & `col=5` (or rather at any char `col>1` in a line terminated by EOF) results in it skipping the last *actual* char of the line : `hello\nhello\nhell_EOF` instead of `hello\nhello\nhell_oEOF`.
3. Trying with the 1st char in the last line (`col==1` in line terminated by EOF)results in the error message (`\n Invalid Index.`) being thrown.

As far as my intuition is concerned, I reckon a flaw when dealing with line termination (`'\n'`,`EOF`) & how it is counted, as well as loop counters in general, but I'm not getting it.

**The idea/algorithm :**

- Get source file from user
- Get index from user (line, col)
- Copy from source to a tmp file till (user's index -1 col).
- Now, allow user to write strings to tmp file's buffer.
- Once user terminates input, copy from user's index to tmp till `EOF`.
- Rename/ Remove+Rename tmp as user's source file's name.

The code below does all the real talking :

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

/* Likely error region in chknmove(), chkncpy() and/or main() ;
   All other functions used are also provided */

long long lncnt(FILE *lcount){
/* counts the number of lines in a file with fgets() */
    rewind(lcount); /* ensures lines counted from beginning */
    long long lines=0; char line[501];
    while((fgets(line,501,lcount))!=NULL){
        lines++;
    }
    rewind(lcount); /* leaves fptr @ 0,0 rather than EOF */ 
    return lines; 
}
int chknmove(FILE *tomove, long long line, long long col){
/* Function to check & move FILE* to certain line/col */
    rewind(tomove); /* make sure fptr is at beginning of file */
    int f=0; /* set check-variable to 0 for successful */
    if(line<1 || col<1)
        f = -1; /* Ln,col cannot be -ve or even 0 -> 1st col is @ 1ln,1col in any non-empty file */
    else{
        long long i,q; i=1;q=0; /* i = lines seen, q = cols seen */
        /* i init to 1 for ease of comprehension v/s testing 'line-1' */
        while(i<line || q<col){ /* loop must iterate until i==line && q==col */
            int ch = fgetc(tomove); /* int to store EOF */
            if(ch==EOF){
                f=-1; break; /* if file ends before reaching index, failed. */
            }
            else if(ch=='\n') {
                if(i==line){
                    f=-1; break;/* if line ends before reaching col in ln, failed. */
                }
                i++; q=0; /* else , increase i by 1 and set q (col) to 0 */
            }
            else
                q++; /* any other character is 'normal' , just increment q (col) by 1 */
        }
    }
    if(f==0){ 
        fseek(tomove,-1,SEEK_CUR); 
        /* since index must be checked, loop reaches it -> fseek(-1) causes *next* r/w to fptr to be on the index . */
        return 0;
    }
    else{
        /* f != 0 : moving has failed. */
        printf("\n Invalid Index.\n");
        return -1;
    }
}
int chkncpy(FILE *source, FILE *dest,long long beginln, long long begincol, long long endln, long long endcol){
    rewind(source); int f=0;
    if(beginln<1 || begincol<1 || endln<beginln || endcol<1 || (beginln==endln && endcol<begincol))
        f=-1; /* line/col must be >= 1 in non-empty file, copying done top to bottom (begin-index <= end-index ) */
    else{
        if(chknmove(source,beginln,begincol)==0){
        /* loop begins if begin-index is valid */
            long long i,q; i=beginln;q=begincol; /* i = lines, q = cols */
            while(i<endln || q<endcol){
                /* while end-index is not reached : !(i==endln && q==endcol) */
                int ch = fgetc(source);
                if(ch==EOF) {f=-1; break;} /* File ends b/w begin-index & end-index - failed. */
                else if(ch=='\n') {
                    if(i==endln) {f=-1; break;} /* endln ends before reaching endcol - failed */
                    i++; q=0;
                    fputc(ch,dest); /* valid '\n' put in dest file */
                }
                else{
                    q++; fputc(ch,dest); /* valid char put in dest file */
                }
            }
        }
        else f=-1; /* if begin-index is invalid, failed. */
    }
    if(f==-1){
        /* if f != 0 : chkncpy() failed */
        printf("\n Invalid Index.\n");
        return -1;
    }
    else /* if f remains == 0 */ return 0;
}
long long lastlncol(FILE *fyl){
    rewind(fyl); /* makes sure fptr @ beginning */
    chknmove(fyl,lncnt(fyl),1); /* move to last line */
    long long cnt=0; /* cnt stores no. of chars in last line */
    while(1){
        int g = fgetc(fyl);
        if (g==EOF)
            break; /* EOF not counted */
        else if(g=='\n'){
                cnt++;break; /* \n is counted as a char, but also as EOL */
            }
        else
            cnt++; /* all other chars counted */
    }
    rewind(fyl); /* leaves file at its beginning */
    return cnt;
}
long long lcc(FILE *fyl,long long line){
    rewind(fyl); int f = chknmove(fyl,line,1); /* moves fptr to line */
    long long cnt=0;
    if(f==0){
        while(1){
            int g = fgetc(fyl);
            if (g==EOF)
                break;
            else if(g=='\n'){
                cnt++;break;
            }
            else
                cnt++;
        }
        rewind(fyl);
        return cnt;
    }
    else
        return -1;    
}
void writer(FILE *write, int ctrl){
    printf("\n Terminate Input with \"/end/\".\n\n   Type below :\n\n");
    char in[501]; /* str that stores input line-by-line */
    char *p; int o;
    while(1){
        fgets(in,501,stdin); /* takes line from user */
        if((p=strstr(in,"/end/"))!=0){ 
            /* if line has "/end/", all chars till /end/ are written to file and input loop breaks */
            o = p-in;
            fprintf(write,"%.*s",o,in);
            break;
        }
        else{
            /* writes line to file */
            fputs(in,write);
        }
    }
    if(ctrl==0){
        /* in some cases, file must not be closed yet , hence ctrl is taken */
        int s = fclose(write);
        if(s==EOF) printf("\n Error ");
        else printf("\n Success.\n");
    }
}
void eat() /* clears stdin */
{
    int eat;while ((eat = getchar()) != '\n' && eat != EOF);
}

int main(){
    /* main to add/insert to file @ given index */
    char fadd[501];/* filename str */ 
    printf("\n Filename : "); scanf("%500[^\n]",fadd);
    FILE * add = fopen(fadd,"r");
    if(add==NULL)
        perror("\n Error "); /* if file does not pre-exist */
    else{
        long long line, col; char sep; printf("\n Index : "); scanf("%lld%c%lld",&line,&sep,&col); /* takes index in ln-char-col form */
        eat(); /* clears stdin */
        FILE * tmp=fopen("Temp.Ctt","w"); /* opens a tmp file to write */
        if(tmp==NULL)
            perror("\n Error "); /* failed - tmp file could not be created to write */
        else{
            int f; /* success var */
            if(line==1 && col>1){
                /* if user wants to insert @ a col>1 in line 1 */
                f = chkncpy(add,tmp,1,1,line,col); /* all below calls intend to write till 1 char before the char @ given index */
            }
            else if(line>1 && col>1){
                /* if user wants to insert @ a col>1 in any line>1*/
                f = chkncpy(add,tmp,1,1,line,col-1);
            }
            else if(line>1 && col==1){ //ERRORS - ignores the '\n' of line-1
                /* if user wants to insert @ a 1st col in line>1 */
                f = chkncpy(add,tmp,1,1,line-1,lcc(add,line-1));
            }
            else if(line==1 && col==1){
               /* if user wants to insert @ 1,1 (no moving/copying needed) */
                f=0;
            }
            else{
                printf("\n Invalid Index.\n");f=-1;
            }
            if(f==0){
                writer(tmp,1); 
                /* calls function to allow user to write to fptr , with ctrl != 0, so writer() *won't* fclose(tmp) */
                chkncpy(add,tmp,line,col,lncnt(add),lastlncol(add));
                /* copies all characters from index till EOF */
                int ok = fclose(tmp); fclose(add);
                if(ok==EOF){
                    /* if closing tmp was unsuccessful, the file on disk may be corrupted/incomplete, so must be removed */ 
                    remove("Temp.Ctt");perror("\n Error ");

                }
                else{
                    if(rename("Temp.Ctt",fadd)==0)
                        printf("\n Success.\n");
                    else{
                        /* on Windows & some other non-POSIX systems, file cannot be renamed to pre-existing filename , hence delete original */
                        remove(fadd);
                        if(rename("Temp.Ctt",fadd)==0)
                            printf("\n Success.\n");
                        else{
                            /* if rename still unsuccessful, throw an error, remove tmp file and give up */
                            remove("Temp.Ctt");
                            perror("\n Error ");
                        }  
                    }
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

*In case of any missing details or inadvertent errors, please comment and I will correct them.*

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221092/discussion-on-question-by-user13863346-attempting-to-insert-or-add-into-a-te).

Comment: @SamuelLiew If and when a comment thread appears to grow a bit large, other than moderator intervention , is there a way for us to move it to chat ourself ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my *self-answer* , issues with `chknmove()` and `chkncpy()` were resulting in ' *glitching* ', those have been fixed below.

The below is ready-to-compile , and generously commented and spaced, and hence is actually larger than the *main idea*, which is encapsulated in `chknmove()` and `chkncpy()` - so these have been placed at the top of the code.

Hope this question/answer is useful to others in the future.

```c
#include <stdio.h> // For file & console I/O
#include <string.h> // For strstr() in writer()

int chknmove(FILE *tomove, long long line, long long col){
    /* Moves FILE* to given ((line,col) -1 char) , such that next char read from FILE* will be @ (line,col)
     Checks validity of index as it moves : if col not in line || EOF encountered, returns -1. */

    rewind(tomove); // rewind file 'just in case'

    int f = 0 ; // control variable which stores state (succeeded/failed) of chknmove()

    if (line < 1 || col < 1) 
    {
        f=-1; 
        printf("\n Illegal Index.\n");
        // Follows 1-based line/col index : -ve values are illegal
        return -1;
    }
    else {
        long long i,q; i = q = 0; // i = lines encountered ; q = chars encountered in line i ; both are 0-based

        while(i < line){
            int chk = fgetc(tomove); // 
            if(chk == EOF){
                printf("\nInvalid %s - beyond EOF.\n", (i == line -1 ) ? "Column" : "Line"); 
                f = -1; break;
            }
            else if(chk == '\n'){
                if(i==line-1 && q == col-1) 
                /*  1. This allows for user to directly point to the '\n' char , allowing him to append to line 
                    2.(line/col - 1) : since i & q are 0-based   */
                    break;
                else{
                    if(i == line-1 ){
                        // except if target index was the '\n' , reading beyond newline @ target line is invalid, since '\n' terminates line
                        printf("\nInvalid column for line %lld.\n",line); 
                        f=-1; break;
                    }
                    i++; q=0; // if not @ target line , reset and continue 
                }
            }
            else if(i == line-1  && q == col-1 ) // if dest index reached, break .
                break;
            else // if non-EOF , non-\n char encountered, increment q and continue.
                q++;
        }

        if(f==0){
            fseek(tomove,-1,SEEK_CUR); // So that the after returning/exiting chknmove() , the char read from FILE* is @ line,col
            return 0;
        }
        else
            return -1;
    }
}
int chkncpy(FILE* source, FILE *dest, long long beginln, long long begincol, long long endln, long long endcol) {
    /* Copies everything from FILE *source to FILE *dest within begining index and terminating index , if they're valid
        Returns -1 if they're invalid.*/

    if (beginln < 1 || begincol < 1 || endln < beginln || endcol < ((endln == beginln) ? begincol : 1))
        // -ve indexes and reading/writing backwards is illegal
        return -1;

    long long i, q; // i -> lines && q -> chars 
    int f=0;
    if(chknmove(source,beginln,begincol)==0){ 
        // checked if begining index is valid and if so, moved to it.

        i=beginln; q=begincol; // i & q have same base as line & col , so 1-based

        while(1){
            int ch = fgetc(source);
            if(ch==EOF){
                printf("\nInvalid Terminating Index.\n");
                f=-1; break;
            }
            else if(ch=='\n'){
                if(i==endln && q==endcol){
                    fputc(ch,dest);
                    break;
                }
                else{
                    if(i==endln){
                        printf("Invalid column for line %lld.\n",endln);
                        f=-1; break;
                    }
                    i++; q=1; // q set to 1 -> q is 1-based !
                    fputc(ch,dest);
                }
            }
            else if(i==endln && q==endcol){
                fputc(ch,dest); break;
            }

            else{
                q++; fputc(ch,dest);
            }
        }
    }
    else
        f=-1;
    
    if(f==0)    return 0;
    else    return -1;
}
long long lcc(FILE *fyl,long long line){ 
    // L.C.C. == line char count , i.e, count of chars in a line (including the \n).

     int f = chknmove(fyl,line,1); /* attempt moving to line, store returned val */

    long long cnt=0; // cnt -> number of chars found 
    if(f==0){ // if line exists , then :
        while(1){
            int g = fgetc(fyl);
            if (g==EOF) // EOF checked in case line is last line
                break;
            else if(g=='\n'){ // '\n' is EOL , hence it is counted and then loop is terminated .
                cnt++; break;
            }
            else
                cnt++;
        }
        rewind(fyl);
        return cnt;
    }
    else
        return -1; // if line doesn't exist, return -1    
}
int clone(FILE *wfrm,FILE *wto){
    // clones wfrom ("Write From ") onto wto ("Write To") until EOF is encountered.

    while(1){
        int a =fgetc(wfrm);
        if(a==EOF)
            break;
        else
            fputc(a,wto);                    
    }

    return 0;
}
void writer(FILE *write){
    // Allows basic console line-level I/O for writing to FILE * 

    printf("\n Terminate Input with \"/end/\".\n\n\tType below :\n\n");
    char in[501]; /* str that stores input line-by-line */
    char *p; int o;
    while(1){
        fgets(in,501,stdin); /* takes line from user */
        if((p=strstr(in,"/end/"))!=0){ 
            /* if line has "/end/", all chars till /end/ are written to file and input loop breaks */
            o = p-in;
            fprintf(write,"%.*s",o,in);
            break;
        }
        else{
            /* writes line to file */
            fputs(in,write);
        }
    }
}
void eat() /* clears stdin */
{
    int eat;while ((eat = getchar()) != '\n' && eat != EOF);
}
int main(){
    /* main to add/insert to file @ given index */

    char fadd[501]=""; // String to store fname
    printf("\n Filename : "); scanf("%500[^\n]",fadd); eat(); // Take fname, clear stdin .
    FILE * add = fopen(fadd,"r"); // open file

    if(add==NULL)
        perror("\n Error "); 
    else{ 
        // If File is loaded for reading successfully

        long long line, col; char sep; // line, col and seperating char make up the index
        printf("\n Index : "); scanf("%lld%c%lld",&line,&sep,&col); eat(); // take index, clear stdin

        FILE * tmp=fopen("Temp.Ctt","w"); // open a temporary file
        if(tmp==NULL)
            perror("\n Error ");
        else{
            int f;
            if(line>=1 && col>1){ // copy till the line , col-1
                f = chkncpy(add,tmp,1,1,line,col-1);
            }
            else if(line>1 && col==1){ // copy till line-1 , last char  
                f = chkncpy(add,tmp,1,1,line-1,lcc(add,line-1));
            }
            else if(line==1 && col==1){ // no moving/copying necessary at all 
                f=0;
            }
            else{
                printf("\n Invalid Index.\n");f=-1;
            }
            if(f==0){ // if Index was not invalid 

                writer(tmp); // let user write to temp file 
                clone(add,tmp); //clones the rest of add to tmp - both are *not* fclosed
                int ok = fclose(tmp); fclose(add);
                if(ok==EOF){
                    /* if closing tmp was unsuccessful, the file on disk may be corrupted/incomplete, so must be removed */
                    remove("Temp.Ctt");perror("\n Error ");

                }
                else{
                    if(rename("Temp.Ctt",fadd)==0)
                        printf("\n Success.\n");
                    else{
                        /* on Windows & some other non-POSIX systems, file cannot be renamed to pre-existing filename , hence delete original */
                        remove(fadd);
                        if(rename("Temp.Ctt",fadd)==0)
                            printf("\n Success.\n");
                        else{
                            /* if rename still unsuccessful, throw an error, point user to temp file and give up */
                            perror("\n Error ");
                            printf("\n %s lost. File-buffer exists as %s in cwd.\n",fadd,"Temp.Ctt");
                        }  
                    }
                }

            }
            else
                remove("Temp.Ctt");
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

*Any constructive critique which may improve the answer is welcome. In case of any inadvertent errors or missing details, please comment and I will reply ASAP.*

Comment: @chqrlie I'm not sure what you mean by *test if index has been reached before attempting to read the next byte from the file*  Its a loop - 'before' and 'after' vary by iteration .... As for inserting at `1,2` in a 1 byte file, it does what it should : 1) copy the 1st byte to `tmp`, writes user input till `"\end\"` and then rename/remove + renames `tmp` too original. Its not failing, and why should it ?

Comment: @chqrlie did you mean empty file with just `EOF` ?

Comment: in the body of a `for(;;)` loop, **first** test if the current position is index: `if (i == line-1 && q == column-1) return 0;` **then** read the next byte, update the counters, and reject invalid index values.

Comment: I'm sincerely curious , as to why , @chqrlie .. What am I missing ?

Comment: *did you mean empty file with just `EOF`?* No, I mean a file that contains a single byte, say `A`, the file size is `1` as reported by `ls` or `dir` or the finder. `EOF` is not a byte, it is not part of the file, it is a special value returned by `fgetc()` to indicate that no more bytes can be read because of end-of-file or read-error.

Comment: @chqrlie appending to a file containing just `Q` at `1,2` with `B` , results in a file containing `QB` ( like it should, since I'm writing to the tmp file )

Comment: @chqrlie I'm sincerely saying that it works after running *this exact* sample code (Clang, Mac , thought that doesn't matter) - have you too tried running it ?

Comment: @chqrlie `chknmove()` will only be engaged to move to `1,1` which exists , since `main()` tells `chkncpy()` to copy from `1,1` to `line, col-1` , basically `chknmove()` does nothing .

Comment: Indeed, it does work, but passing `col-1` for the `col` argument is confusing. Your code is difficult to prove right in all cases. My proposed alternative is simpler and removes the need for `fseek` and `lcc` too.

Comment: @chqrlie It seems incredibly not-confusing to me , since it makes it explicit that I want to copy till col-1 only. Also, `chkncpy()` and `lcc()` are used in many other places in my project, I'd not be removing them anyways. Idk,  subjective... Sure, your answer is pretty good, perhaps more linear and thus clearer, just that this an alternative that works (just as well ?)  for me.  And how do you lose the `fseek(-1)` ? You will *have to* read the actual index to know if it's valid (it may be just after the EOF or a \n ) , so you will have to seek back 1 byte , yes ?

Comment: To give credit where it is due, *some* core parts of this method were inspired from *this* answer by dxiv : https://stackoverflow.com/a/63627701/13863346

Answer (score 0):

Your code is too complicated:

- The different cases of copying the beginning of the file should be merged into a single function call that copies data up to and excluding the byte at column `col` on line `line`.
- Then you copy from user input.
- Finally you copy the rest of the input file.
- The code assumes lines and columns are numbered from `1`. It may be obvious but you should specify this as it may not be obvious to everyone.
- The style is very difficult to read: you should use horizontal space around binary operators, after keywords, `,` and `;` and before `{`. Cramming multiple statements on a single line is not a good idea either.

Here is a simplified version. As often, most of the code is for error handling:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void flush_line(FILE *fp) { /* read the rest of the current line */
    int c;
    while ((c = getc(fp)) != '\n' && c != EOF)
        continue;
}

int copy_file(FILE *from, FILE *to) {
    int c;
    while ((c = getc(from)) != EOF) {
        if (putc(c, to) == EOF)
            return EOF;
    }
    return 0;
}

int copy_lines(FILE *from, int line1, int col1, FILE *to) {
    int c, line = 1, col = 1;
    for (;;) {
        if (line >= line1 || (line == line1 && col >= col1))
            break;
        if ((c = getc(from)) == EOF)
            break;
        if (putc(c, to) == EOF)
            return EOF;
        col++;
        if (c == '\n') {
            line++;
            col = 1;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

int writer(FILE *write) {
    char in[501]; /* str that stores input line-by-line */
    char *p;

    printf("\n Terminate Input with \"/end/\".\n\n   Type below :\n\n");
    while (fgets(in, 501, stdin)) {
        if ((p = strstr(in, "/end/")) != NULL) {
            /* if line has "/end/", all chars till /end/ are written to file and input loop breaks */
            int o = p - in;
            if (fprintf(write, "%.*s", o, in) < 0)
                return EOF;
            break;
        } else {
            /* writes line to file */
            if (fputs(in, write) < 0)
                return EOF;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

int main() {
    /* main to add/insert to file @ given index */
    const char *temp_filename = "Temp.Ctt";
    char fadd[501];/* filename str */

    printf("\n Filename : ");
    if (scanf("%500[^\n]", fadd) != 1)
        return 1;
    flush_line(stdin);

    FILE *add = fopen(fadd, "r");
    if (add == NULL) {
        perror("\n Cannot open input file");
        return 1;
    }
    int line, col;
    /* read the index: 1 based line and column numbers */
    printf("\n Index : ");
    if (scanf("%d%*c%d", &line, &col) != 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "invalid input\n");
        return 1;
    }
    flush_line(stdin);
    FILE *tmp = fopen(temp_filename, "w");
    if (tmp == NULL) {
        perror("\n Cannot create temporary file");
        fclose(add);
        return 1;
    }
    if (copy_lines(add, line, col, tmp)) {
        perror("\n Error copying beginning of file");
        fclose(add);
        fclose(tmp);
        remove(temp_filename);
        return 1;
    }
    if (writer(tmp)) {
        perror("\n Error writing user input");
        fclose(add);
        fclose(tmp);
        remove(temp_filename);
        return 1;
    }
    if (copy_file(add, tmp)) {
        perror("\n Error copying remaining file contents");
        fclose(add);
        fclose(tmp);
        remove(temp_filename);
        return 1;
    }
    fclose(add);
    if (fclose(tmp) < 0) {
        /* if closing tmp was unsuccessful, the file on disk may be corrupted/incomplete, so must be removed */
        perror("\n Error closing temporary file");
        remove(temp_filename);
        return 1;
    }
    if (rename(temp_filename, fadd) == 0) {
        printf("\n Success.\n");
        return 0;
    }
    /* on Windows & some other non-POSIX systems, file cannot be renamed to pre-existing filename , hence delete original */
    if (remove(fadd)) {
        perror("\n Cannot remove input file");
        remove(temp_filename);
        return 1;
    }        
    if (rename(temp_filename, fadd) == 0) {
        printf("\n Success.\n");
        return 1;
    }
    /* if rename still unsuccessful, try and copy contents */
    tmp = fopen(temp_filename, "r");
    if (tmp == NULL) {
        perror("\n Cannot re-open temporary file, output is in Temp.Ctt");
        return 1;
    }
    add = fopen(fadd, "w");
    if (add == NULL) {
        perror("\n Cannot re-open input file, output is in Temp.Ctt");
        fclose(tmp);
        return 1;
    }
    if (copy_file(tmp, add)) {
        perror("\n Error copying temporary file to input file");
        fclose(add);
        fclose(tmp);
        return 1;
    }
    fclose(tmp);
    if (fclose(add) < 0) {
        perror("\n Error closing input file");
        return 1;
    }
    /* throw an error, remove tmp file and give up */
    remove(temp_filename);
    printf("\n Success.\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Well, this sure seems to solve most of the ugly issues in my code - except : It treats `\n` as a reset point , which means I cannot '*append*' to a  line (and maybe cant write to `line > 1 col==1`)  , which is the same problem occurring here(https://stackoverflow.com/a/63730935/13863346)  as well  - we **need** to count the `\n` as a char too, and reset @ the *first char* of the *next* line ! Any suggestions on how can this be done ?

Comment: @user13863346:  The index is the insert point: `1,1` means insert text at the beginning of line 1. If line 1 has 8 characters `ABCDEFGH`, inserting at index `1,9` appends to line 1, in other words inserts the text input by the user between the `H` and the newline `\n` of the first line. Inserting at `1,10` has the same effect as `2,0` or `2,1`. The code can be changed to make `1,10` behave the same as `1,9`, with a modified test: `if (c == '\n') { if (line == line1) { ungetc(c, fp); break; } else { line++; col = 1; }}`

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I can neither confirm nor deny the allegation that my answer is "*too complicated*' ; )  I have fixed my code, and posted that as a second answer - to me the code I corrected is just alright and anyways is part of a slightly large project so\\_(0_0)_/ . Perhaps if you have a while , take a look at it ! Thanks again.

Comment: @user13863346: Study my `copy_lines` function, it is much simpler and handles all cases. You can easily modify it to reject *invalid* index values.